# Editing Integrated Terminal in VS Code

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, visual-studio-code

I am trying to edit the "current directory" while I am in my integrated terminal in VS Code.

I am running macOS Sierra 10.12.6. VS Code 1.21.1.

Within the integrated terminal, I was able to change the directory by directly editing the PS1 variable, (aka, PS1='\w \u'), but when I save it, it only saves to that specific instance of VS Code. If I open up a new VS Code window, it reverts back to the original PS1 variable.

I checked other Stack Overflow questions and answers, and people tend to advise editing the .bash_profile or another .bash file found in the root. I was not able to find this file in my root, or any other file that helped.

Does anybody know where I can directly edit the PS1 variable, or where VS Code loads the bash profile?

Also, please note I am not trying to edit my actual Terminal settings, only the one that is loaded for VS Code.

Thank you.

Comment: Try creating it with that line, might be the quickest solution.

Comment: @kabanus Do you mean edit the PS1 variable every time I open a new instance of VS Code? I'd prefer to edit whatever profile is being loaded into the integrated terminal.

Comment: I meant create the missing `.bash_profile` file (or `.bashrc`) if it does not exist - then add your line in there.

Comment: I ended up using "sudo nano bashrc" in my ~/etc directory, which is being referenced by both my macos terminal and my integrated terminal inside of VS Code. Thanks for the help, in any case!

Comment: feel free to write your own answer for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

I went to my `~/etc` directory, edited the `.bashrc` file via `sudo nano .bashrc`, and edited the `PS1` variable in there.

That `.bashrc` file was being referenced for both my MacOS Terminal, and the integrated terminal for VS Code. So changing anything in there affected both of those terminals. I hope this information helps!